# Trying to get a QDialog to expand to its contents

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt6

I am trying to create a derived QWidget that I can reuse.  I want to have a border around the widget.  I have this working so far.  My problem is that the parent QDialog is not completely expanding so I need to expand it manually after it launches.  I would prefer not setting a specific size, but letting the dialog to grow as required.

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QRadioButton, QSizePolicy, QDialog

import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFrame, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel


class MyNestedWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dollars_edit = None
        self.dollar_edit = None
        self.dollar_radio = None

        main_frame = QFrame(self)
        main_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.Shape.Panel)
        main_frame.setLineWidth(2)

        label = QLabel("Choose one")
        v_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        v_layout.addWidget(label)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.dollar_radio = QRadioButton('Amount')
        layout.addWidget(self.dollar_radio)
        self.dollar_edit = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(QLabel('$'))
        layout.addWidget(self.dollar_edit)
        layout.addStretch()
        v_layout.addLayout(layout)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.percent_radio = QRadioButton('Percent')
        layout.addWidget(self.percent_radio)
        self.percent_edit = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.percent_edit)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel('%'))
        layout.addStretch()
        v_layout.addLayout(layout)
        v_layout.setContentsMargins(5, 0, 5, 5)

        main_frame.setLineWidth(2)
        main_frame.setLayout(v_layout)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)


class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = MyNestedWidget()
        top_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        top_layout.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.setLayout(top_layout)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    test = False
    if test:
        widget = MyNestedWidget()
        widget.show()
    else:
        dialog = MyDialog()
        dialog.exec()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

This is what it looks like on running:

[image]

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the layout to a child widget, but not to the actual one. Doing that will prevent the *parent* to know anything about that layout.

In fact, that `main_frame` is quite useless.
Remove it, then just subclass QFrame instead of QWidget, apply those frame settings to `self`, and finally call `self.setLayout(v_layout)`.

Alternatively, use `self` as argument of the layout constructor instead of calling `setLayout()`.

Also, size policies only make sense for widgets that are added to a layout that also contains other widgets, so remove them as they are completely useless.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.  Removing main_frame worked beautifully (see edits above)

Comment: @jordanthompson There's no need for an answer that shows the complete code, which would hardly be helpful to others than you, the important thing is explaining the problem and the concept behind its solution. And, in any case, that solution should never be put in the question, but as an answer; if you want, you could add your own answer, but, as said above, that would be quite pointless, and it wouldn't add anything actually new that would justify a further answer.